# Size Classes and Stack Views Axis constraints conflicts

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints, size-classes, uistackview

I'm trying something really simple and I do not understand the constraint conflict resulting. Let me explain:

I have a nice view controller with a full screen vertical `UIStackView` (contraints set to 0 to top, leading, trailing and bottom) with two views inside.

The top view as a constrained height of 200pt, the bottom view has no constraint. As the stack view has a Fill distribution mode, everything is fine.

Now, I want the stack view to switch to horizontal axis on landscape on iPhones. So, on my storyboard I select the w**Any**|h**Compact** size class, uninstall the height constraint, add a width constraint, and select horizontal axis...

The behavior works alright, unfortunately, it detects a constraint conflict I can't explain :

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba62c1b7f0 H:[UIStackView:0x7fba62c0a3c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fba62c0bd10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba62c1b890 H:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7fba62c0a3c0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fba62c0bd10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba62c1ba80 H:[UIView:0x7fba62c15420(200)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba62d1c230 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fba62c0a3c0.leading == UIView:0x7fba62c15420.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba62dcad80 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UIView:0x7fba62c15420]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fba62c0a3c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba62dc69d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fba62c0bd10(736)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba62c1ba80 H:[UIView:0x7fba62c15420(200)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

So if someone can tell me what is wrong!

Comment: If you post your code for removing the constraints and adding the new constraints, it will be a lot easier to help you. :-)

Comment: There is no code :) : Everything has been done with Size Classes within Interface Builder!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem and it appears to possibly be a bug in UIStackView where an internally generated constraint from the previous/default size class is lingering. This workaround (Swift) works for me:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
  super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

  self.setNeedsLayout()
  self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me: `layoutIfNeeded` seems to call back `traitCollectionDidChange` and all finishes in an infinite loop. But thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't run into the infinite loop but I have now seen where this only helped in a very isolated situation. After considerable debugging it appears that size classing the axis of a stack view just has issues at the moment.